# Null attribute in MVC 5 not rendering. What kind of magic is this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

```
<form name="mailform" id="mailform" method="post" action="@(ViewBag.Test)" class="testForm">
```

What I thing that this will render my action attribute like `action=""` (in case of `ViewBag.Test = null`) but I am confused with ASP.NET MVC's behaviour.

When ViewBag.Test is not defined than my action attribute is not rendering. For confirm I open the View-source in Chrome and Firefox and none of both have action attribute for my form. I also check it by change the text but action attribute is remain not rendering.

Can someone explain what is it? And the link that I can verify it's the common behaviour of ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: Are you viewing the source (ctrl + u in chrome) or just inspecting element? Inspecting element will "tidy up" the HTML, removing tags that don't have values

Comment: I'm also interested in knowing why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the MVC framework (or more specifically the Razor engine) that is choosing to remove it. They are known as 'conditional attirbutes' and appear to have been introduced in MVC 4. [See here for more information](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway//asp-net-4-beta-released) (search for: Conditional attribute rendering), or [read this](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/conditional-attributes-in-razor-view-engine-and-asp.net-mvc-4).

I guess the answer to why it has been implemented is likely just for convenience, so coders don't have to write ugly checks to decide if an attribute should be included or not.

If you want to force the empty attribute, then you can just handle null values. For example, like this...

```
<form name="mailform" id="mailform" method="post" action="@(ViewBag.Test ?? "")" class="jeetForm">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that MVC 5 form will help you much more.

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{}

Null is converted to string.empty when used as you did.

I suggest you that read a little more about ASP.NET MVC. You just start the learning process.

Answer (score 0):

You must handle null values outside.

Just check after null or empty or whitespace outside.

```
@{ var link = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Test) ? ViewBag.Test : string.Empty;
  var isSet = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Test);
}
```

And use isSet and link for your logic.

Null is transformed in nothing by Razor, string.Empty is something else (it will render the referenced attribute, in your case action).